# Sorting a 2D numpy array by multiple axes

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of shape (N,2) which is holding N points (x and y coordinates). For example:

```
array([[3, 2],
       [6, 2],
       [3, 6],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 3]])
```

I'd like to sort it such that my points are ordered by x-coordinate, and then by y in cases where the x coordinate is the same. So the array above should look like this:

```
array([[3, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 6],
       [5, 3],
       [6, 2]])
```

If this was a normal Python list, I would simply define a comparator to do what I want, but as far as I can tell, numpy's sort function doesn't accept user-defined comparators.  Any ideas?

---

EDIT: Thanks for the ideas! I set up a quick test case with 1000000 random integer points, and benchmarked the ones that I could run (sorry, can't upgrade numpy at the moment).

```
Mine:   4.078 secs 
mtrw:   7.046 secs
unutbu: 0.453 secs
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Using [lexsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy.lexsort):

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.array([(3, 2), (6, 2), (3, 6), (3, 4), (5, 3)])

ind = np.lexsort((a[:,1],a[:,0]))    

a[ind]
# array([[3, 2],
#       [3, 4],
#       [3, 6],
#       [5, 3],
#       [6, 2]])
```

---

`a.ravel()` returns a view if `a` is `C_CONTIGUOUS`. If that is true, 
[@ars's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706624/190597), slightly modifed by using `ravel` instead of `flatten`, yields a nice way to sort `a` *in-place*:

```
a = np.array([(3, 2), (6, 2), (3, 6), (3, 4), (5, 3)])
dt = [('col1', a.dtype),('col2', a.dtype)]
assert a.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']
b = a.ravel().view(dt)
b.sort(order=['col1','col2'])
```

Since `b` is a view of `a`, sorting `b` sorts `a` as well:

```
print(a)
# [[3 2]
#  [3 4]
#  [3 6]
#  [5 3]
#  [6 2]]
```

Comment: Ah, I'd seen lexsort in the docs, but I couldn't figure out how it would apply to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I often have difficulty understanding documentation.  Examples tend to be far more illuminating. The trouble is, after playing with examples, I reread the docs and find out the docs were perfectly clear... :-)

Comment: This is making a copy of the array, no?

Comment: @Noah: yes, this is making a new array.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if it's possible to sort() a numpy array by multiple indices without making an intermediate copy.  This is what numpy.ndarray.sort does, but only for record arrays AFAICT.

Comment: @Noah: I've modified my answer above to show how to sort a numpy array on multiple indices, in-place.

Comment: just a warning: the in-place version doesn't seem to give the correct answer (not sure if there was always a problem or if something changed in numpy)

Comment: I get the columns sorted separately, so the x/y coordinate pairs are no longer paired correctly: `print(a)` yields `[[2 2], [3 3], [3 3], [4 5], [6 6]]` (using the example code from your answer)

Comment: @Noah: Thanks for the bug report. The problem was that my code assumed `a` had dtype `int32`. Your `a` has a different dtype, probably `int64`. I've modified the code above to handle any dtype.

Comment: note the inplace sort does not work in general since ravel() *can* create an intermediate copy. I think in the particular way that the array is organized in OPs question allows you to do it in place but just don't try to apply this to a more general case without verifying that a ravel() can be done in place.
Also, chaining a ravel with a view `b = a.ravel().view()` obfuscates the fact that `b` might be a view of `a` or a view of a copy of `a`.
Sorry if this sounds pedantic, I just wanted to leave this warning for others :)

Comment: @toes: You are absolutely right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Note that `lexsort` uses the **last entry** in the sequence **as primary key**, the second-last as secondary etc. This caught me off-guard. This answer does the right thing, but it is easily overlooked.

Comment: For an arbitrary 2D array: `np.lexsort(a.T[::-1])`

Answer (score 24):

The title says "sorting 2D arrays". Although the questioner uses an `(N,2)`-shaped array, it's possible to generalize unutbu's solution to work with any `(N,M)` array, as that's what people might actually be looking for.

One could `transpose` the array and use slice notation with negative `step` to pass all the columns to `lexsort` in reversed order:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.randint(1, 6, (10, 3))
>>> a
array([[4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 5],
       [3, 5, 5],
       [1, 5, 5],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [5, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [4, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 1],
       [5, 3, 4]])

>>> a[np.lexsort(np.transpose(a)[::-1])]
array([[1, 5, 5],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 1],
       [3, 5, 5],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [4, 2, 5],
       [4, 3, 4],
       [5, 2, 2],
       [5, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: What if I only want to sort column 1, then column 3. 
How should I change your code?

Answer (score 4):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) can be used to solve these kind of processing-on-nd-array problems in an efficient fully vectorized manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.sort(a)  # by default along axis=0, but configurable
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.complex_sort`.  This has the side effect of changing your data to floating point, I hope that's not a problem:

```
>>> a = np.array([[3, 2], [6, 2], [3, 6], [3, 4], [5, 3]])
>>> atmp = np.sort_complex(a[:,0] + a[:,1]*1j)
>>> b = np.array([[np.real(x), np.imag(x)] for x in atmp])
>>> b
array([[ 3.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  6.],
       [ 5.,  3.],
       [ 6.,  2.]])
```

Comment: I think you win the cleverness award; I wouldn't have thought of making the y-coordinates imaginary!

Comment: But dog slow!  Sorry, I didn't really consider performance when I posted this.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with the same thing and just got help and solved the problem. It works smoothly if your array have column names (structured array) and I think this is a very simple way to sort using the same logic that excel does:

```
array_name[array_name[['colname1','colname2']].argsort()]
```

Note the double-brackets enclosing the sorting criteria. And off course, you can use more than 2 columns as sorting criteria.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: removed bad answer.

Here's one way to do it using an intermediate structured array:

```
from numpy import array

a = array([[3, 2], [6, 2], [3, 6], [3, 4], [5, 3]])

b = a.flatten()
b.dtype = [('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4')]
b.sort()
b.dtype = '<i4'
b.shape = a.shape

print b
```

which gives the desired output:

```
[[3 2]
 [3 4]
 [3 6]
 [5 3]
 [6 2]]
```

Not sure if this is quite the best way to go about it though.

Comment: That doesn't quite work, because it loses the association between x and y for my points.

Comment: Hm. When I run that, I get an error on the `b.shape = a.shape` line: "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged". I'm running Python 2.6.2, with numpy 1.2.1.

Comment: I'm running Python 2.5.4 with numpy 1.3.0.  Try upgrading the version of numpy.

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to do it:

```
from numpy import array
a = array([(3,2),(6,2),(3,6),(3,4),(5,3)])
array(sorted(sorted(a,key=lambda e:e[1]),key=lambda e:e[0]))
```

It's pretty terrible to have to sort twice (and use the plain python `sorted` function instead of a faster numpy sort), but it does fit nicely on one line.