# Sort a Numpy Python matrix progressively according to rows

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

I have searched around and tried to find a solution to what seems to be a simple problem, but have come up with nothing. The problem is to sort a matrix based on its columns, progressively. So, if I have a numpy matrix like:

```
import numpy as np
X=np.matrix([[0,0,1,2],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,4],[0,0,0,3],[0,1,2,5]])
print(X)
[[0 0 1 2]
 [0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 4]
 [0 0 0 3]
 [0 1 2 5]]
```

I would like to sort it based on the first column, then the second, the third, and so on, to get a result like:

```
Xsorted=np.matrix([[0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,4],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,1,2],[0,1,2,5]])
print(Xsorted)
[[0,0,0,3]
 [0,0,0,4]
 [0,0,1,1]
 [0,0,1,2]
 [0,1,2,5]]
```

While I think it is possible to sort a matrix like this by naming the columns and all that, I would prefer to have a method for sorting that doesn't depend so much on how big the matrix is. I am using Python 3.4, if that is important.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you _have_ to use numpy?

Comment: I don't care about using numpy, but I would like to keep the results in matrix form if at all possible, or at least be able to readily translate results to matrix form.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to be particularly fast, but you can always convert your rows to tuples, then use Python's sort:

```
np.matrix(sorted(map(tuple, X.A)))
```

You can also use `np.lexsort`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26036376/10601) to a [somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2706605/10601):

```
X[np.lexsort(X.T[::-1])]
```

The lexsort approach appears to be faster, though you should test with your actual data to make sure:

```
In [20]: X = np.matrix(np.random.randint(10, size=(100,100)))

In [21]: %timeit np.matrix(sorted(map(tuple, X.A)))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.23 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit X[np.lexsort(X.T[::-1])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
data = [[0,0,1,2],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,4],[0,0,0,3],[0,1,2,5]]
x  = pandas.DataFrame(data)
# order of columns to sort
z = x.sort([0,1,2,3])
output = z.as_matrix()
```

`output`:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 3],
   [0, 0, 0, 4],
   [0, 0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1, 2],
   [0, 1, 2, 5]])
```

Comment: Added some explanation and output.

Comment: Everyone --thanks very much for the help! It turns out that all of these solutions will be useful for me at some point!