# Sort multi-dimension numpy array along a dimension

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

Let's say I have a 2D numpy array, and I want to sort it as if it was a standard Python list, i.e. putting its rows themselves in (lexicographical) order, as opposed to the cells along an axis. So from this:

```py
>>> a = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

I want to arrive at this:

```py
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```

Unfortunately, it is not so easy:

```py
>>> np.sort(a, axis=0)
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])

>>> sorted(list(a))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

>>> np.sort(list(a))
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

I know this might (should!) be super basic, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, never mind, duplicate of [Sorting a 2D numpy array by multiple axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706605/sorting-a-2d-numpy-array-by-multiple-axes?rq=1); just use `lexsort` (or the other alternatives under that question):

```py
>>> a[np.lexsort((a[:, 1], a[:, 0]))]
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 1]])
```