# Sort 2D list in ascending order

Tags: python, list, algorithm, numpy, matplotlib

I've created random points and drawn a graphic with the plot and data. Then I'm saving this figure as a image.

How am I able to do the following?

- Sort this random point list , lower coordinates to upper coordinates.

  Example list:  `[[1,3], [1,2], [1,1]]`

  Target: `[[1,1], [1,2], [1,3]]`
- And using the target list as an example:

  Index 0 = [1,1] , Index 1 = [1,2] etc.
  How can I do math between these indexes like this:  `Y0 - Y1/ X0 - X1`

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

points = np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(18,2))
print(points)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], '.',color='k')


plt.savefig("graphic.png",bbox_inches="tight")
result = cv2.imread("graphic.png")
cv2.imshow("Result",result)
```

[image]

Graphic drawn with random created points . I'm trying to sort this points lower Y to higher,Y . For example on this graphic you can see minimum coordinate is  (1,0) and second minimum coordinate is (7,1) .

Comment: To sort use `sorted(lst)`, where  `lst = [ [1,3], [1,2], [1,1] ]`

Comment: That `key` is completely unnecessary @darry

Comment: Can you share a minimal example @emily? Seems unclear what your asking

Comment: @yatu--you're right.  I place the key automatically since I forget that sort automatically sort lists that way by default.

Comment: @yatu i edited for you

Comment: To sort a numpy array see [Sorting a 2D numpy array by multiple axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706605/sorting-a-2d-numpy-array-by-multiple-axes). `points[np.lexsort(np.transpose(points)[::-1])]`

Comment: Well, you need to use the result somehow. E.g. `sorted_points = points[np.lexsort(np.transpose(points)[::-1])]` and then `plt.plot(sorted_points[:,0], sorted_points[:,1], '-',color='r')`

Comment: @JohanC It's working like lower x and lower y to higher x and y , but i need primarly lower y to higher y .

Comment: Just leave out the `[::-1]`:   `sorted_points = points[np.lexsort(np.transpose(points))]`

Comment: @JohanC that's it . It is working. If you can write this as a answer i would like to give a accept vote .

Comment: Well, stackoverflow considers this a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a 2D numpy array by multiple axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706605/sorting-a-2d-numpy-array-by-multiple-axes)

Answer (score 0):

Their is this function in python called sorted. It is an amazing thing you know, we all love it. It basically sorts any list you give it. It truly is a wonderfull tool and I use it a lot when coding. All you have to do is simple:

**Input**

```
MyList = [13,7,4,4]
sortedList = sorted(MyList))
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 4, 7, 13]
```

Just like that your list is sorted. It can even sort you list which contains sublist. Just change the variable MyList to your own list.
Now what if we wanted to reverse it, that's simple just set reverse to true

```
MyList = [13,7,4,4]
sortedList = sorted(MyList,reverse=True)
```

And of course this works with strings
Also there is another way of doing implementing the sort function just like this:

```
MyList = [13,7,4,4]
MyList.sort()
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a 2D list, use a lambda like this:

```
mylist = [[1,3], [1,2], [1,1], [0,9]]
l1 = sorted(mylist, key = lambda elem: elem[0]) 
l2 = sorted(mylist, key = lambda elem: elem[1])
```

The first one sorts after the first element in sublists, the second one sorts after the second. The output is different,

```
[[0, 9], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [0, 9]]
```