# Sorting A 2-Dimensional Array on Multiple Axes

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
tasks = [["LNWBN","2017-08-13","2017-12-24","Corey","Kyle","Kaleb","Reuben"], 
["NSXEN","2017-08-20","2017-09-18","Kai"], 
["DNMDC","2017-06-19","2017-08-07","Kaleb","Kai","Kyle","Reuben"], 
["UYWEQ","2017-04-23","2017-07-18","Corey","Kyle","Reuben","Kai"], 
["LIVNH","2017-11-01","2017-12-24","Kaleb","Kai"]]
```

I would like to sort it by the third column followed by the first column so that the result is:

```
tasks = [["UYWEQ","2017-04-23","2017-07-18","Corey","Kyle","Reuben","Kai"], 
["DNMDC","2017-06-19","2017-08-07","Kaleb","Kai","Kyle","Reuben"], 
["NSXEN","2017-08-20","2017-09-18","Kai"], 
["LIVNH","2017-11-01","2017-12-24","Kaleb","Kai"],
["LNWBN","2017-08-13","2017-12-24","Corey","Kyle","Kaleb","Reuben"]]
```

I tried using lexsort:

```
a = np.array(tasks)
ind = np.lexsort((a[:,2],a[:,0]))    
sorted_tasks = a[ind]
```

which is the top solution from here [Sorting a 2D numpy array by multiple axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706605/sorting-a-2d-numpy-array-by-multiple-axes)
but I get the following error:

```
  ind = np.lexsort((a[:,2],a[:,0]))
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

I don't HAVE to use numpy, but that's the only way I found to sort 2D arrays by more than one axis

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try python's `sorted`:

```
sorted(tasks, key=lambda x: (x[2],x[0]))
```

Output:

```
[['UYWEQ', '2017-04-23', '2017-07-18', 'Corey', 'Kyle', 'Reuben', 'Kai'],
 ['DNMDC', '2017-06-19', '2017-08-07', 'Kaleb', 'Kai', 'Kyle', 'Reuben'],
 ['NSXEN', '2017-08-20', '2017-09-18', 'Kai'],
 ['LIVNH', '2017-11-01', '2017-12-24', 'Kaleb', 'Kai'],
 ['LNWBN', '2017-08-13', '2017-12-24', 'Corey', 'Kyle', 'Kaleb', 'Reuben']]
```