# How to extrapolate some points in a 3D sapce in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, sorting, extrapolation

I have some points in 3d and want to do a sort of extrapolation on them. My points are in a regular `x` and `y` grid and have some splits. I want to extraploate points beyond the splits. I copied a simplified data set having three splits. I extrapolate the end side of the first split, both sides of the middle split and front side of the third one. In case of `10` splits I extrapolate end side of the first, both sides of split numbers `2` to `9` and front side of the last. These are my coordinates (`x`, `y` and `z`):

```
surf_points=[[np.array([[1.,19.,4.],[1.,20.,4.],[2.,19.,4.5],[2.,20.,4.5],[3.,20.,4.]]),\
              np.array([[4.,19.,3.2],[4.,20.,3.],[5.,19.,3.],[5.,20.,3.1],[6.,19.,3.1],[6.,20.,3.1]]),\
              np.array([[7.,19.,4.1],[7.,20.,4.2]])]]
```

At the moment, each split is sorted firstly in `x` direction, then in `y` direction. I change it to be sorted firstly based on `y` and then `x` using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706605/sorting-a-2d-numpy-array-by-multiple-axes). Then `surf_points` will be:

```
[[np.array([[1.,19.,4.],[2.,19.,4.5],[1.,20.,4.],[2.,20.,4.5],[3.,20.,4.]]),\
 np.array([[4.,19.,3.2],[5.,19.,3.],[6.,19.,3.1],[4.,20.,3.],[5.,20.,3.1],[6.,20.,3.1]]),\
 np.array([[7.,19.,4.1],[7.,20.,4.2]])]]
```

**First splits extrapolation**

For first split I want to add two points at the end of each `y` grid. First `y` grid is `19` and second one is `20`. `x` and `y` of new points are fixed and defined: `(3.,19.)` and `(4.,19.)`. `z` value is calculated from the previous two points existing in each `y` grid. In case of having only one point in the grid, I simply copy `z` of that single point. First `y` grid has two points with `z` values  `4.` and `4.5`. The first extrapolated point is the third one in this grid and its `z` will be calculate as `4.5 + (4.5-4)/2 = 4.75` (`z of last point + (z of last point - z of one point before the last)/2`)  and for the second extrapolated point I update the the last and one before last points to have it as `4.75 + (4.75-4.5)/2 = 4.875`. So, two extrapolated point of the first `y` grid will be `(3.,19.,4.75)` and `(4.,19.,4.875)`. I do the same for second `y` grid (`20`). This grid has three points and two added points will be `(4.,20,3.75 #4+(4-4.5)/2)` and `(5.,20, 3.625# 3.75+(3.75-4.)/2)`. These four points will be added at the end of first split.

**Middle splits extrapolation**

For middle splits I add four points to front side and four point to end side. The end side is exactly like end side of first split. For front side `x` and `y` values of extrapolated point will be less than existing one. They will be `(2.,19.)` and `(3.,19.)` in first `y` grid and `(2.,20.)` and `(3.,20.)` in second `y` grid. I start to calculate the `z` firstly for second point as (`z of first point + (z of first point - z of second point)/2`). It will be calculated from existing next two points as `3.2 + (3.2-3.)/2.` which makes `3.3` and then use this `3.3` value for calculating z value of the first point in this grid  `3.3 + (3.3-3.2)/2.` which makes `3.35`. I do the same for the second `y` grid.

**Last splits extrapolation**

For the last split I want to copy what I did for the front side of the second split, but it has only one point in each `y` grid and I only copy that value for extrapolated ones.
Finally new extrapolated points should be added to previous ones and I want my list to be as:

```
all_points=[[np.array([[1.,19.,4.], [1.,20.,4.], [2.,19.,4.5], [2.,20.,4.5], [3.,20.,4.],\
                       [3.,19.,4.75], [4.,19.,4.875], [4.,20,3.75], [5.,20, 3.625]]),\
             np.array([[2.,19.,3.3], [3.,19.,3.35], [2.,20., 2.923], [3.,20., 2.95],\
                       [4.,19.,3.2], [4.,20.,3.], [5.,19.,3.], [5.,20.,3.1], [6.,19.,3.1], [6.,20.,3.1],\
                       [7.,19.,3.15], [8.,19.,3.175], [7.,20., 3.1], [8.,20., 3.1]]),\
             np.array([[5.,19.,4.1], [6.,19.,4.1], [5.,20.,4.2], [6.,20.,4.2],\
                       [7.,19.,4.1], [7.,20.,4.2]])]]
```

To clarify my problem, a fig is uploaded. In the fig extrapolated points of each split are shown with differen colurs and symbols.
I do appreciate any help to write my idea as an algorithm in python.

[image]

Comment: This is rather difficult to read. I get quite discouraged after reading the first paragraph already. Is there no way to put this question in a more organised fashion?

Comment: Dear @trincot, maybe the fig helps. Just look at black dots: they are in two sets. Their y is 19 or 20. each of sets I want to extrapolate two more points in first split. four black rectangles are created based on the rules are explained. Then, in second split, I want to do extrapolation in both sides of the points because tthis split is sandwiched by two. For last one I extrapolate in the begining of the split.

Comment: You're missing the point. No one wants to parse your prose long enough to get to the figure. Please be more concise.

Comment: Dear @Mad Physicist, you are absolutely right but the problem is that I could not explain it in any ther way. You have already a part of this big issue.

Comment: Break it up into smaller topics as you started doing and write them up very carefully.

Comment: Dear @Mad Physicist, the smaller piece was the issue you commented already (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076098/how-to-extrapolate-points-of-a-regular-grid-in-python). That is only for black dots (first array) of this question. That is editted now.

Comment: Or something like (in a minimal version) : input(s) -> command(s) -> output / desired output. With data, no text.