# How to extrapolate points of a regular grid in python

Tags: python, numpy, extrapolation

I have a numpy array of points and want to extend my point (`x`, `y` and `z`) in a defined direction. This is my array:

```
coordinates=np.array([[1., 19., 4.], [2., 19., 4.5], [1., 20., 4.],[2., 20., 4.5], [3., 20., 4.]])
```

These points are on two `y` grids: `19` and `20`. I want to extend my points in these grid lines. First grid has two point. `x` and `y` coordinates of extrapolated points are fixed. `y` equals the grid value (19 or 20) and `x` equals one unit more that the last point of the grid. For first grid the new `x` and `y` of two points are `(3.,19.)` and `(4.,19.)` and `z` should be calculated as:

```
z of last point + (z of last point - z of one point before the last)/2
```

In case of having just one point in the grid, I copy the value of that point. In the first grid, `z` value of first extrapolated point is :

```
4.5 + (4.5-4)/2 = 4.75
```

and for the second point is

```
4.75 + (4.75-4.5)/2 = 4.875
```

I want to do the same for the next grid (`y=20`) to finally add all four point to the existing array:

```
all_points=np.array([[1.,19.,4.], [1.,20.,4.], [2.,19.,4.5], [2.,20.,4.5], [3.,20.,4.],\
                     [3.,19.,4.75], [4.,19.,4.875], [4.,20,3.75], [5.,20, 3.625]])
```

I tried the following but firstly I have no idea how to generate `z` value dynamically. At the moment it is calculating the same z values for the new two generated points of each grid. Another issue is that my code is not effiecient and I believe there are much faster ways to do it:

```
nums, counts=np.unique(coordinates[:,1],return_counts=True) # gives the y grids
new_y=nums
cum=np.cumsum(counts)-1
new_x=[]
for i in cum:
    new_x.append (coordinates[i,0])
new_x=np.array(new_x)
new_x_y=[]
for m, n in zip (new_x, new_y):
    new_x_y.append([m,n])
    new_x_y.append([m+1,n])
new_x_y=np.array(new_x_y)
z_difference=[]
for i in cum:
    z_difference.append((coordinates[i,-1]-coordinates[i-1,-1])/2)# to find the difference of last two points of each grid
new_z=[]
for i in range (len(cum)-1):
    new_z.append (coordinates[cum[i],-1]+z_difference)#to find the new z of each extrapolated point
new_z=np.array(new_z)
all_z=np.repeat (new_z, repeats=new_z.shape[1], axis=1)
final_arr=np.hstack ([new_x_y, all_z.T])
```

In advance, I do appreciate any help to solve my problem in python.

Comment: Are you trying to to bilinear extrapolation?

Comment: Dear @Mad Physicist, I do not know that much details about bilinear extrapolation. I read the Wiki page of this method but did not understand it completely. I just want to add two more points at the end of each grid and the z value of new points on grid should be calculated based on previous ones. to be honest, this problem is part of a bigger one I already opend in SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67074121/how-to-extrapolate-some-points-in-a-3d-sapce-in-python). There is a fig in the page of bigger problem and I only copied the points are shown as blacl dots here.

Comment: This is rather difficult to read. I get quite discouraged after reading the first paragraph already. Is there no way to put this question in a more organized fashion? Please use paragraphs, and less inline code. It is really hard to help as it is right now.

Comment: Dear @Gulzar, I want to xetrapolate two more points in each `y` grid. For example I have two y grids and finally I make `4` new points. `x` and `y` coordinates of the new points are fixed but their `z` should be calculated based on the existing previous points.